# Proving an index is within list bounds given (index + 1) is within bounds

Tags: idris

Let's say we have a `list : List a`, and we want to use its first and second elements:

```
case inBounds 1 list of
     Yes prf => doSmth (index 0 list) (index 1 list)
     No _ => doSmthElse
```

Unfortunately, this does not typecheck: indeed, `prf` is a proof that `InBounds 1 list` holds, but while it's obvious to us humans that `InBounds 0 list` immediately follows, it still needs to be shown to the typechecker.

Of course, one might write a helper proof

```
inBoundsDecr : InBounds (S k) xs -> InBounds k xs
inBoundsDecr {k = Z} (InLater y) = InFirst
inBoundsDecr {k = (S k)} (InLater y) = InLater (inBoundsDecr y)
```

and then use it in the `Yes` branch like this:

```
case inBounds 1 list of
     Yes prf => let prf' = inBoundsDecr prf in
                    doSmth (index 0 list) (index 1 list)
     No _ => doSmthElse
```

but it seems to be quite verbose.

So, what's the most concise and/or idiomatic way to do this in Idris?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a proof of `xs` that gives you some information about `xs`, it is better to use `with` instead of a `case`. Then the compiler can see that the argument can be determined by the proof. See this chapter in the tutorial: [Views and the "with" rule](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/views.html)

```
addHs : List Nat -> Nat
addHs xs with (inBounds 1 xs)
  addHs xs | p = ?hole
```

Pattern-matching on `p` gives `Yes prf`, then `Yes (InLater y)`, then `Yes (InLater InFirst)`, and updating `xs` to `(x :: y :: xs)`. And so you can easily use `x` and `y`:

```
addHs : List Nat -> Nat
addHs xs with (inBounds 1 xs)
  addHs (x :: y :: xs) | (Yes (InLater InFirst)) = x + y
  addHs xs | (No contra) = 0
```

The problem with that is – here it doesn't work properly. If you check if `addHs` is total, the compiler warns you, because it thinks that another `Yes (InLater p)` could be reached. Not sure why, the totality checker isn't that great. But in theory it should work fine. :-)

Other than your initial attempt (which may be more verbose, but you don't depend that much on the totality checker), you could of course add a dummy `Yes (InLater p)` case or stop there and do something like

```
addHs : List Nat -> Nat
addHs xs with (inBounds 1 xs)
  addHs (x :: xs) | (Yes (InLater prf)) = x + (index 0 xs)
  addHs xs | (No contra) = 0
```

Or being somewhat unsafe and assert that the case is unreachable:

```
addHs : List Nat -> Nat
addHs xs with (inBounds 1 xs) proof q
  addHs (x :: y :: xs) | Yes (InLater InFirst) = x + y
  addHs (x :: xs) | Yes (InLater p) = assert_unreachable
  addHs xs | No _ = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Turns out, adding `addHs (x :: xs) | (Yes InFirst) impossible` indeed type checks and satisfies the totality checker. Now I'm not sure how the totality checker works at all, if the type checker can see that this case is impossible yet the totality checker asks for it. This suggests they are perhaps two not-so-much-tied algorithms?